# Android: Indeterminate progress bar for ServerCall routine.

Tags: android, json, gson, android-progressbar

I'm working on a simple I.M android app for class that makes queries to a server and displays the results (i.e messages) on a ListView. One of the requirements is that the app display an indefinite progress bar while the query is being made. 
This means that I have to set a ProgressBar widget to View.VISIBLE when the query begins and to View.INVISIBLE when the query is over. 
The trouble I'm having is that the query is a background function defined in a different Java class, so while I'd like to do something like this:

```
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ...
        ...
        uploader.execute(myCallSpec);
        ...
        ...
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

This doesn't work, because the server call runs in the background. Using this code, it's as if the progress bar was never even displayed.

How do I set the progress bar to be displayed when the service call begins and then back to invisible when the call is completed?

Comment: Is uploader a AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's set as: uploader = new ServerCall(); Where ServerCall is a class which extends the AsyncTask class. I'm not allowed to make any changes to that class though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead with AsyncTask

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   private ProgressBar pb;
   public MyTask(ProgressBar pb) {
      this.pb = pb;
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      //Your query here.
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

 MyTask mt = new MyTask(pb);
 mt.execute()
```

But in real project I suggest you to use something like [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice). As well AsyncTask doesn't handle activity lifecycle by default.

**UPD:**

There is two ways to have access to ProgressBar instance inside AsyncTask:

1. Just declare it as inner class and save ProgressBar in field of your outer (main) class
2. Pass reference via constructor. (see modified example)

Comment: Ok, I can see how this strategy will work, but how do I access pb and other external variables from within the class?

Comment: @JosephFaulkner see modified answer

Answer (score 0):

In your AsyncTask class in `onPostExecute` method you should stop progressbar

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

It call(on ui thread) after task is finished

Comment: Ok, how would I access the pb like this when it is defined in another class?

Comment: add parameter in constructor